# Remove previous selected date from the calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, xcode4.2

I have integrated the calendar month view in my app and that's work fine but my problem is I can't remove the previous selected date from the calendar.

I am using the code from [this tutorial](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244).

And i have face this problem:-
[image]

I want only one date to be selected at a time.

Please help,
And thanks for any help or suggestion.